# How to Create Makefile to compile and MPI C programs in netbeans?

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, makefile, mpi

I have this file as my Makefile in netbeans,

```
 CC = mpicc           #compiler name
 CFLAGS = -Wall       #extra compiler flags
 OUT_NAME = example   #executable name

 all: *.c
   $(CC) -o $(OUT_NAME) $(CFLAGS) *.c

 clean:
   rm $(OUT_NAME) *.o
```

I want to run MPI programs from my Netbeans using command `mpirun -np 4 filename`. How can i compile and generate output filename as the same name of input file? Also how to pass `-np #` parameter to mpirun in netbeans , so that netbeans ask no of processors each time it executes ??

Btw i am getting this error when building project

```
      make: *** No rule to make target `*.c', needed by `all'.  Stop.

      MAKE FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 52ms)
```

Comment: when defining a macro in a makefile, unless that macro needs to be re-evaluated each time it is invoked (not likely) the use `:=` rather than `=`

Comment: targets that do not actually produce a output file need to have a line similar to `.PHONY: all clean`  near the top of the makefile

Comment: the macro: `CFLAGS` is missing several very useful items.  Suggest: `CFLAGS := -g -c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std-c99`  or something very similar for compiling and suggest adding a `LFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99`

Comment: strongly suggest separating the compile steps from the link step in the `all` target

Comment: in general, the link step should depend on the list of object files and a (perhaps) a list of libraries.    The compile step should depend on a list of source files and a list of dependency files for the #include statements in the source.  suggest adding:  `OBJS := $(SRC:.c=.o)`  and `DEPS := $(SRC:.c=.d)`  then adding a compile rule similar to: `%.o: %.c %.d <newline><tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $< -o $@ -I.   suggest the `all` target be: `all: $(OUT_NAME)` and adding a rule: `$(OUT_NAME): $(OBJS)<newline><tab>$(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)  $(LIBS)

Comment: the dependancy *.c will not get a list of the .c files. rather insert a macro similar to: SRC := $(wildcard .c) then use $(SRC) rather than *.c   Note: `make` does not perform a `glob` operation on wild card characters.  However: $(wildcard *.c)  will perform a `glob` operation

Comment: if deciding to use the dependency file approach (always a good idea) then will need to add, at the bottom of the makefile, something similar to: `ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif`   Note: the ifnew "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean" is so `make` does not reproduce the *.d files when the target is `clean`

Comment: @user3629249 Most of your suggestions are good and correct (a little hard to follow spread across seven comments though). That said you did get one thing wrong. make **does** support direct globbing (see [Using Wildcard Characters in File Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcards)) it just generally isn't a good idea to depend on it.

Comment: What version of `make` is netbeans using?

Comment: Your right, I probably should have made it an answer rather than a string of comments.  It seemed to me that the comments did not answer the OPs question, rather they just indicated where the makefile could be improved

Comment: Make version `GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
`

Comment: @user3629249 Can you make it an answer, please ??